# Check if exist Chain between x and y exist in a Directed Graph

Tags: c++, graph

I have this code which check if exist a path(road) between 2 vertex (x and y) in a directed graph.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Graf
{
private:
int Vf;
list<int> *adj;
public:
// Constructor
Graf(int Vf)
{
    this->Vf = Vf;
    adj = new list<int>[Vf];
}

void addEdge(int vf, int w) // add 
{
    adj[vf].push_back(w);
}

bool isGRoad(int first, int second)
{
    if (first == second) // cazul in care 
        return true;

    bool *visited = new bool[Vf];
    for (int i = 0; i < Vf; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    list<int> myQueue;

    visited[first] = true;
    myQueue.push_back(first);

    list<int>::iterator index;

    while (!myQueue.empty())
    {
        first = myQueue.front();
        myQueue.pop_front();

        for (index = adj[first].begin(); index != adj[first].end(); ++index)
        {
            if (*index == second)
                return true;

            if (!visited[*index])
            {
                visited[*index] = true;
                myQueue.push_back(*index);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
};


int main()
{
int nrVf;
cin >> nrVf;

Graf graf(nrVf);
int ok = -5;

for (int i = 1; i <= nrVf; ++i)
{
    cout << i << ": ";
    cin >> ok;

        while (ok != -1)
        {
            graf.Graf::addEdge(i, ok);
            cin >> ok;
        }

    ok = 0;
}

int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;

if (graf.isGRoad(x, y))
    cout << "Exista drum de la " << x << " la " << y << ".\n";
else
    cout << "Nu exista drum de la " << x << " la " << y << ".\n";

return 0;
}
```

Now i want to change my code to check if exist a chain between x and y. The difference between path(road) and chain is that on the chain the direction is not important. I can't figure it out how to check if it's a chain and not just a path. Can someone give some help?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, then if you modify addEdge so when you add edge {A, B} also add edge {B, A} (and add some check to avoid duplicates) your code would find chains instead of pathes.

Comment: I know that part but i can't understand what checks should i add.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur i tried what you said but i get crash. And debugger says std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<int,std::allocator<int> > >::_Prevnode(...) returned 0x5.